# Set default tab in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, formatting, default-settings

Default tab in Outlook is 0.5 and it makes bulleted lists look bad.

I can change tab size per each and every paragraph in each and every email each and every time I make a list but that's excruciatingly annoying. Is there a way to set the default?

Comment: Word is what Outlook sues as it's editor (if it's installed) have you tried (re)setting the default in Word?

Comment: Sure thing... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Word is what Outlook uses as its editor if it's installed.

Try (re)setting the editor defaults/settings (for the Tab size, etc.) in Word instead of in Outlook.